# UIView Animation just work one time than it doesn't work

Tags: swift, animation, layout, constraints

I try to do an animation for my view but if just work in first time which is isOpen = true it work but when I call my function again isOpen = false nothing changes?

Perent view is self (UIView). Child is label(UILabel).

```
private func expansionView(isOpen: Bool) {
        if isOpen {
            label.backgroundColor = .white
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                 label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor),
                 label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: 15),
             ])
            
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
                self.layoutIfNeeded()
            }) { (_) in
                
            }
        } else {
            label.backgroundColor = .clear
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                 label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor),
                 label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor , constant: 15),
             ])

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
                self.layoutIfNeeded()
            }) { (_) in
                print("Animation Completed!!!")
            }
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: second time you get constraint break in debug ?

Comment: In my debug console says Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
 Try this: 
  (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
  (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000056c910 UILabel:0x7fc61e605620'Name'.centerY == AuthTextField.AuthField:0x7fc61fb04ed0.centerY   (active)>

Comment: actually you did not remove the previous constraints ... thats why your constraints breaks  and you did not get desired result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have two constraints to make one of them active.
You can also animate changing label's background color to clear. And you can simplify your function like below.

```
// define both vertical constraints
var constraintToCenterYAnchor: NSLayoutConstraint!
var constraintToTopAnchor: NSLayoutConstraint!

// where you init your view..
init() {
    // init your constraints
    constraintToTopAnchor = label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor)
    constraintToCenterYAnchor = label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor)

    // set and activate other constraints once.
    label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 15).isActive = true

    // update background color of the label
    label.backgroundColor = .clear
    label.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
}

// simplify your function
private func expansionView(_ isOpen: Bool) {
    constraintToTopAnchor.isActive = isOpen
    constraintToCenterYAnchor.isActive = !isOpen
    
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) {
        self.label.layer.opacity = isOpen ? 1.0 : 0.0
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have two contraints to activate and deactivate ...

```
lazy var centerXConstraint = label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor)
lazy var topConstraint = label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor , constant: 15)
    
    
    init() {
        label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: 15).isActive = true
    }
    private func expansionView(isOpen: Bool) {
        if isOpen {
            label.backgroundColor = .white
            
            centerXConstraint.isActive = false
            topConstraint.isActive = true
            
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
                self.layoutIfNeeded()
            }) { (_) in
                
            }
        } else {
            label.backgroundColor = .clear
            
              centerXConstraint.isActive = true
              topConstraint.isActive = false
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
                self.layoutIfNeeded()
            }) { (_) in
                print("Animation Completed!!!")
            }
        }
        
    }
```